# Parse $http result to get specific items in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get a json-style result from an `$http GET` in angularJS.
It looks like this:

```
{
    "meta":{
    "limit":1000,
},
"objects":[
    {
        "custom_pk":"1",
        "linked_client":null,
        "resource_uri":"/api/v1/card_infos/1"
    },
    {
        "custom_pk":"2",
        "linked_client":null
    }, ...
```

I'd like to have an array which contains all `custom_pk` values to do something like:

```
$scope.validate_pk = function(val){
    if (val in myArray)
        // do some stuff
```

How do you create myArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the objects like this:

```
var json = ... the javascript object shown in your question
var custom_pks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.objects.length; i++) {
    custom_pks.push(json.objects[i].custom_pk);
}
// at this stage the custom_pks array will contain the list of all
// custom_pk properties from the objects property
```

Comment: Thx it works! As I'm going to do these kind of operations a lot, is there a simpler/cleaner way to proceed? Am I supposed to write some loops when I want to parse json?

Comment: You could also move this common functionality in a reusable function that you would invoke. The name of the property could also be dynamic:  `custom_pks.push(json.objects[i]['custom_pk']);` allowing you more flexibility if you want to externalize this functionality and work against any property.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use the .map() Array function:

```
var myArray = json.objects.map(function(item){
    return item.custom_pk;
});
```

Array.map() takes a function as an argument. This function is executed once for each value in the array and gets passed (item, index, list) as parameters. The result of the map function is a new array containing the results of the passed function.